# Is there a way to pass keyboard shortcuts from a PC to a Mac while using ultraVNC?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

At work I normally use a Windows laptop. My group recently bought a Mac mini to start playing with mobile. A monitor was not purchased. Instead it was deemed that we would access the mini with ultraVNC viewer.

This works for most things, but I am a heavy keyboard shortcut person. Trying to use cut and paste shortcuts just jumps my editor all around. It is very frustrating and slows down my productivity. Is there a way when I hit ^-c on my PC, in the viewer that it emulates ⌘-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to make use of keyboard combinations by using the ALT or possibly the Windows Key.

Example to Copy: Use ALT C or Windows Key C.

Comment: Alt C worked.  Not awful since it's about where command would be.

Comment: That's great! But how about the other modifier keys? How can I emulate the remote Mac's Alt key from a Windows PC?

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting Windows-C when in the VNC viewer.

Comment: That didn't work for me.

Comment: You'll have to look around at different VNC viewers to see which have Mac support.